# Text cutout effect with an image on a div that has written text. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a clock application that shows digital time. The problem is that I would like to add a cutout effect to that digital time where there is an image added that makes the digital time visible.

The thing is that, the in order for the time to be displayed(as in visible), they(digital time numbers that change in relative to time) have to be on a higher z-index scale from the rest of the stuff. I can not make the numbers visible so, they would have that cutout effect or a knockout effect as many call it. The numbers are layered as a z-index: 9; as they are the highest layer in that application, as there is content beneath the digital time.

The digital time has to look like it has a cutout effect. I can make the cutout effect with a still image that has a still text or numbers, but can not make the effect look like a cutout effect in my own project added to that digital time.

Basically, the digital time has a z-index: 9; and there is a white image beneath the time that has a z-index: 8; . The thing is that, I can not make a cut out effect so that everything would be as it is, as in the content on the screen has to remain the same. The digital time has to have a cutout effect with an image that can be changed, but at the same time the digital time div has to be the highest layered z-index while the content has to remain the same.

I can change to color of the digital time easily, by writing color: green; into css, but can not make a cutout effect with an image. Is it possible somehow to add an image to numbers that change, while the image is only visible in the area the numbers are?

A webpage that describes using image as a cutout effect:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cutout_text.asp

The content on the webpage is not the one that I need. The need is for the same text, but applied to constantly changing numbers, while at the same time the numbers, or in this case the text, is the way it is on the webpage. Only imagine, that between the white canvas(where the cutout effect was implemented) and the image is another layer that is, for instance, red. That red layer must not have any effects, just a red canvas, but the text has to have that effect.

Does someone know how to solve this kind of issue regarding to css?

Thanks

Comment: What if you just made 10 images, one for each digital number as a cut out and render the 4? images corresponding to the time?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Javascript, for example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("textYouWantToChange");

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var time = pad(now.getHours(), 2) + ":" + pad(now.getMinutes(),2) + ":" + pad(now.getSeconds(),2);
  el.innerHTML = time;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.image-container {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg"); /* The image used - important! */
  background-size: cover; 
  position: relative; /* Needed to position the cutout text in the middle of the image */
  height: 300px; /* Some height */
}

.text {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10vw; /* Responsive font size */
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the text container */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center; /* Center text */
  position: absolute; /* Position text */
  top: 50%; /* Position text in the middle */
  left: 50%; /* Position text in the middle */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Position text in the middle */
  mix-blend-mode: screen; /* This makes the cutout text possible */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div id="textYouWantToChange" class="text">NATURE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working, but the white image I have in my project is a .png image, and it does not work relative to the needs if the white canvas is not .png.

Comment: The image looks like this: https://ibb.co/88h3Jyv . Where the black area is actually white and the red just indicates the size of the image. The black area that is actually white is the place where the digital clock is located. The hour and minute is two separate div-s that are place on top of that .png image. The area that is transparent(including red color) is the place where other content is located and must be transparent. There is a tap function that removes the .png image when tapped on the screen. Then, there should be not images visible, also the digital time disappears.

Comment: Can you add a link to your white image?

Comment: I colored the image, because the white .png was not visible on that site. The black is actually white and the red indicates the size of the image beyond the black.

Comment: Basically, it has to work like a filling, like a color, but with an image where the image can be moved to wished location, rather than the time is a cutout.

Answer (score 0):

Found this pen which is better than the current option. It uses masking rather than a cutout approach.

https://codepen.io/nopr/pen/Jdsbx

CSS:

```
   /* Housekeeping */
body {
  background: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

/* Reverse Mask */
.mask {

  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Background to mask */
  background: url("");
  background-position: 0 50%;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -o-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;

 /* Text size and style */
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  padding: 0 15px;

}

/* Variants */

.one {  
  color: transparent;
  text-stroke: 25px;
  background-position: 0 25%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(221,221,221,0.2);
  transition: text-shadow 0.35s linear;
}
.one:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(221,221,221,1), 0 0 0 #ddd;
}

.two {  
  color: transparent;
  text-stroke: 5px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: background-position 1.5s;
}
.two:hover {
  background-position: 0 50%;
}

.three {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0px #ddd;
  text-stroke: 5px;
  transition: text-shadow 0.5s;
}
.three:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="mask one">Stockholm</h1>
<h1 class="mask two">Stockholm</h1>
<h1 class="mask three">Stockholm</h1>
```

Unfortunately I could not apply that to the clock. The clock turns to grey instead of giving an error in the console.